# Use SQL Group By or Window Function to analyse rows in time sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data like the following:

```
+-----+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------------------+
| ID  |  Name  |  Lat  |  Long  |  Speed  |       DateTime       |
+-----+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------------------+
|  1  |  Test  |   121 |  2131  |      0  |  10-11-2018T12:00:00 |
|  1  |  Test  |   121 |  2131  |    100  |  10-11-2018T12:10:00 |
|  1  |  Test  |   121 |  2131  |      0  |  10-11-2018T01:00:00 |
|  1  |  Test  |   121 |  2131  |    102  |  10-11-2018T01:10:00 |
+-----+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------------------+
```

I need to get:

```
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|         |         from          |         to          |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| stop    |  10-11-2018T12:00:00  | 10-11-2018T12:10:00 |
| moving  |  10-11-2018T12:10:00  | 10-11-2018T01:00:00 |
| stop    |  10-11-2018T01:00:00  | 10-11-2018T01:10:00 |
| moving  |  10-11-2018T01:10:00  | null                |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` with `CASE WHEN` and `lead` window function to make it.

```
select CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over( order by (SELECT NULL)) % 2 = 0 THEN 'Move' ELSE 'Stop' END,
       [DateTime] 'from',
       lead([DateTime]) over(order by (SELECT NULL)) 'to'  
from t
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdfd7d552798151fdeba79dec9c977e3)

But I think you might want to use `order by DateTime`

```
select CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by DateTime) % 2 = 0 THEN 'Move' ELSE 'Stop' END,
      DateTime 'from',
      lead(DateTime) over(partition by ID order by DateTime) 'to'   
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table on itself using `ID` and adjacent `DateTime` values. This considers the scenario where rows aren't always alternating between stopped and moving.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t1.Speed <> 0 THEN 'moving'
    ELSE 'stop' END as 'movingStatus',
    t1.DateTime as 'from',
    t2.DateTime as 'to'
FROM MyTable t1, MyTable t2
WHERE
    t1.ID = t2.ID
    t2.DateTime = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM MyTable WHERE DateTime > t1.DateTime)
```